# Как обратиться к внешней переменной из функции в setTimeout

Tags: javascript

Код выглядит примерно вот так:

```
  () => {
    let delay = 1000;
    
    let timerId = setTimeout(function request() {
      Promise.all(
      // здесь что-то делаем
      )
        .then(() => {
        // и здесь хотим перезапустить setTimeout вот таким путем
        timerId = setTimeout(request, delay)
        })
     }, delay)
   }
```

VS Code говорит, что timerId объявлен, но нигде не используется. При этом к `delay` у него претензий нет.

В чём проблема с видимостью `timerId`?
Как перезапустить `setTimeout`?

Comment: А ведь он действительно не используется, Предполагается что таймер может быть остановлен `clearTimeout(timerId)`, а в данном варианте это ни к чему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С `timerId` проблем нет, но в вашем случае оно вообще ни к чему, т. к. вы нигде его **не используете**, а **только присваиваете**.

Скажем, на такой код VS Code ругаться не будет:

```
() => {
    let delay = 1000;
    
    let timerId = setTimeout(function request() {
      Promise.all(
      // здесь что-то делаем
      )
        .then(() => {
        // и здесь хотим перезапустить setTimeout вот таким путем
        timerId = setTimeout(request, delay)
        })
     }, delay);
    
     console.log('timerId', timerId);
}
```

Результат создания таймера нужен лишь если вы хотите его подчищать потом через `clearTimeout`. Если вам оно не надо, то и присваивание в `timerId` не нужно.